# Sharing files between two containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

For couple of hours I am struggling with docker compose. I am building angular app. And I could see the files in the dist directory. Now I want to share these files with the nginx container. I thought the shared volume will do it. But when I add

```
services:
    client:
       volumes: 
            - static:/app/client/dist
    nginx:
          volumes: 
            - static:share/user/nginx/html

volumes:
   static:
```

an try `docker-compose up --build`
I got this error

```
client_1  | EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/app/client/dist'
client_1  | Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/app/client/dist'
client_1  |     at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:863:18)
client_1  |     at rmdirSync (/app/client/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:276:13)
client_1  |     at Object.rimrafSync [as removeSync] (/app/client/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:252:7)
client_1  |     at Class.run (/app/client/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:29:16)
client_1  |     at Class.run (/app/client/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:250:40)
client_1  |     at resolve (/app/client/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:261:20)
client_1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
client_1  |     at Class.validateAndRun (/app/client/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:240:12)
client_1  |     at Promise.resolve.then.then (/app/client/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:140:24)
client_1  |     at <anonymous>
client_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
client_1  | npm ERR! errno 1
client_1  | npm ERR! app@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
client_1  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
client_1  | npm ERR! 
client_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 build-prod script.
client_1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help is fully appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem.

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? @AbdelrhmanHussien I have the same problem. Whenever you attach a volume to a node generated directory, this problem occurs

Comment: I have solved this one yes, in my side the directory was generated to in the process so by the time I was trying to attach a volume to it. it wouldn't be exist yet. So I looked at the angular configuration to make this directory permanent and that fixed  the issue for me. I hope that help

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHussien, did you happened to do this by setting `deleteOutputPath` to `false` in angular.json?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is, as the error suggests, a deadlock situation. Your docker-compose file has 2 services that start approximately, if not, simultaneously. Both of them has some sort of hold on the Docker volume (named, "static"). When Angular executes `ng build`, by default, `--deleteOutputPath` is set to `true`. And when it attempts to delete the output directory, the error message that you received occurs.

If `deleteOutputPath` is set to `false` the issue should be resolved. Perhaps that is sufficient for your needs. If not, as an alternative, having the `--outputPath` set to a temp directory within the project directory and after Angular builds, move the contents into the Docker volume. If the temp directory path is `out/dist` and the volume maps to `dist` this can be used:

```
ng build && cp -rf ./out/dist/* ./dist
```

However, that alternative solution is really just *working around* the issue. To make note, the docker-compose `depends_on` key will not help in this situation as it simply signifies a dependency and nothing to do with "readiness" of the dependent service.

And also to make note, executing `docker volume rm <name>` will have no consequences as a solution here. Remember, both services have a hold on the volume as one is trying to remove it.

Just a thought, haven't tested, as another alternative solution is to delete the contents within the output path. And set the `deleteOutputPath` to `false`, since Angular seems to be attempting to delete the directory itself.

**Update:**

So removing the contents in the output path seems to work! As I mentioned, set `deleteOutputPath` to `false`. And in your `package.json` file, in the scripts object, having something similar to this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:production": "rm -rf ./dist/* && ng build --configuration production",
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @Abdelrhman Hussien. I ran into the same issue, after some brain crackling I read this. @marckassay is right, and spot on. It is pretty logic, ng tries to remove the output folder. But it can't since it is mounted. You can also fix this by going one level deeper (just create a subfolder like `/dist/build`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve it without using named volumes:

```
services:
    client:
       volumes: 
            - ./static-content:client/app/dist
    nginx:
          volumes: 
            - ./static-content:share/user/nginx/html
```

Comment: Still even without named volumes not working, same error

Comment: this is another typo